# Resolve raspberrypi.local to ip address in javascript using mdns-js

Tags: javascript, networking, raspberry-pi2, jmdns, mdns

I have a Raspberry Pi that is connected to my network and a Samsung Gear S that is connected to the same network. The Raspberry Pi is used as a server and the Gear S sends data to it. I currently need to insert the Raspberry Pi IP address manually in the Gear S app whenever I connect to another network. I've found that you can use raspberrypi.local and that the raspberry pi will recognize this address as it owns. My problem is that when I try to post something to the address 
"http://raspberrypi.local:8080/appdata/post" using Javascript, the post doesn't
come true. I suppose that raspberrypi.local cannot be resolved.

I stumbled on mdns-js (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mdns-js) and I think this 
should solve my problem. I want to run the following example:

```
var mdns = require(['mdns-js']);
console.log("Require found");

var browser = mdns.createBrowser();
console.log("Browser created");

browser.on('ready', function () {
    browser.discover(); 
});

browser.on('update', function (data) {
    console.log('data:', data);
});
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error: Script error for "mdns-js"
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror (require.js:140)
```

I use the require function from http://requirejs.org/. Anybody who can help me with this error or better solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: Does the IP on the Raspberry Pi ever change, or is it just sitting on a home network?

Comment: It can change because it is not always connected to the same network.

Comment: Might want to take a look at [this question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13936/find-raspberry-pi-address-on-local-network) then, assuming you can run those commands from the Gear S without root.

Comment: @colonelsanders the problem is I need to do it in Javascript

Comment: Is the Gear app a web app then? Bit confused, sounds like you want to run JS on the Gear S that will find your Pi, which has a non-static address. I'm not aware of any reliable way to do that with client-side JS, apart from running a local scan to find all devices in the private space running on :8080.

Comment: @colonelsanders, yes i'm writing a web app. So you say that there is no other way than doing a local scan?

Comment: Barring any experimental or poorly supported protocols, then yes. But only to _my_ knowledge.